# How can I put the vertical line using multicolumn?

Tags: errors, line-breaking, multicolumn

How can I fix the vertical lines?

```
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
    \caption{Cronograma de Actividades}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
     Objetivos & Actividades/Tiempo (meses) & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Escoger zonas potenciales} & 1. Búsqueda de información&\\&
    de mapas de LAI y &\\
    & de tipos de cobertura  & X &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \cline{ 2- 20}
    \multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & 2. Escoger lugares extremos &  & X & X &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \cline{ 2- 20}
    \multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & 3.Escoger zonas intermedias &  & X & X &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \cline{ 2- 20}
    \multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & 4. Seleccionar los mapas&\\
    & a relacionar con&
    \\ &las variables atmosféricas &  &  & X &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{Definir los transectos} & 1. Búsqueda de información&\\
     &de DEMs y datos atmosféricos & X &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \cline{ 2- 20}
    \multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & 2. Análizar las variables&\\
     &atmosféricas y las topográficas &  & X & X & X &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\ \cline{ 2- 20}
    \multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & 3. Establecer los ríos aereos& \\
    &de humedad atmosférica &  &  &  & X & X & X &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{Evaluar la influencia} & 1. Búsqueda de información&\\
     &de evapotranspiración y &\\
    &de temperatura atmosférica & X &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \cline{ 2- 20}
    \multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & 2. Realizar gráficas de&\\
     &P Vs distancia, P Vs Cobertura,&\\
     &P Vs LAI, P Vs T y P Vs ETP &  &  &  &  &  & X & X & X & X & X &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \cline{ 2- 20}
    \multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & 3. Explicar mediante principios&\\
     &físicos los resultados obtenidos &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & X & X & X & X & X &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{Otros objetivos} & 1. Elaboración de informes&\\
    & escritos y artículos  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & X & X & X & X & X & X & X \\ \cline{ 2- 20}
    \multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & 2. Revisión de los resultados&\\
     &obtenidos y ajustes &\\
    &que sean necesarios &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & X & X & X & X & X &  &  \\ \cline{ 2- 20}
    \multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & 3. Exposiciones, reuniones&\\
     &y discusiones & X & X & X & X & X & X & X & X & X & X & X & X & X & X & X & X & X & X \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \label{actividades}
    \end{table}
    \end{landscape}
```

[image: Vertical lines problem]

Comment: two possibilities: pack the multi-line entries in the second column into `parbox`es, which would provide the necessary height; or add enough `&` to every "short" line to provide enough empty cells to reach across the width of the table.  (recoding the multi-line entries seems to me the better approach.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution, with a simpler code and using the `makecell` package, that allows for multilines cells. I modified the alignment of the second column, using the alignment key inside the cells defined with \makecell, and managed to have a correct spacing between the table and its caption (the default values of the parameters supposes the caption is below the float).

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{array}
\let\belowcaptionskip\abovecaptionskip
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\cellgape{\Gape[4pt]}
\renewcommand\cellalign{lc}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\vspace*{-3cm}\centering
\caption{Cronograma de Actividades}
\begin{tabular}{|*{20}{c|}}
\hline%
 Objetivos & \makecell{Actividades/Tiempo (meses)} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 \\ \hline
Escoger zonas potenciales  & \makecell{ 1. Búsqueda de información \\ de mapas de LAI y \\de tipos de cobertura}  & X &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
\cline{ 2- 20}
 & \makecell{2. Escoger lugares extremos} &  & X & X &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
 \cline{ 2- 20}
 & \makecell{3.Escoger zonas intermedias} &  & X & X &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
 \cline{ 2- 20}
 & \makecell{4. Seleccionar los mapas \\ a relacionar con \\ las variables atmosféricas} &  &  & X &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
 \hline
 Definir los transectos  & \makecell{1. Búsqueda de información \\ de DEMs y datos atmosféricos} & X &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
 \cline{ 2- 20}
 & \makecell{2. Análizar las variables \\ atmosféricas y las topográficas}  &  & X & X & X &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
 \cline{ 2- 20}
 & \makecell{3. Establecer los ríos aereos \\ de humedad atmosférica} &  &  &  & X & X & X &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
 \hline
 Evaluar la influencia & \makecell{1. Búsqueda de información \\ de evapotranspiración y \\ de temperatura atmosférica }& X &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
 \cline{ 2- 20}
 & \makecell{2. Realizar gráficas de \\ P Vs distancia, P Vs Cobertura, \\ P Vs LAI, P Vs T y P Vs ETP} &  &  &  &  &  & X & X & X & X & X &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
 \cline{ 2- 20}
 & \makecell{3. Explicar mediante principios \\ físicos los resultados obtenidos} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & X & X & X & X & X &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
 Otros objetivos & \makecell{1. Elaboración de informes \\ escritos y artículos}   &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & X & X & X & X & X & X & X \\ \cline{ 2- 20}
 & \makecell{2. Revisión de los resultados \\ obtenidos y ajustes  \\ que sean necesarios} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & X & X & X & X & X &  &  \\
 \cline{ 2- 20}
 & \makecell{3. Exposiciones, reuniones \\y discusiones} & X & X & X & X & X & X & X & X & X & X & X & X & X & X & X & X & X & X \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{actividades}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

```
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Escoger zonas potenciales} & 1. Búsqueda de información&\\&
de mapas de LAI y &\\
```

terminates the row early, so the line segments are omitted: you need

```
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Escoger zonas potenciales} & 1. Búsqueda de información&\\&
de mapas de LAI y &&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than splitting the occasionally lengthy material in the second column by hand across several rows and supplying lots of instances of 18 `&` entries, I suggest you use the `tabularx` environment (provided by the package with the same name) and its `X` column type to simplify entering the information. In fact, there will be no need to insert all those extra `&` instances at all. (If you prefer the material in the two text columns to be centered rather than right-aligned, use the `c` column type in the first case and `\Centering` instead of `\RaggedRight` in the second.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % choose margins here
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{rotating} % for sidewaystable environment
\usepackage{tabularx} % for tabularx environment and "X" column type
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for `\RaggedRight` alignment (allows hyphenation, unlike `\raggedright`)
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % provide a bit of "breathing space"
\caption{Cronograma de Actividades} 
\label{actividades}
\medskip % a bit more separation between caption and table
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| l | c @{\hspace*{3pt}} Y | *{18}{c|} }
\hline
Objetivos & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Actividades/Tiempo (meses)}
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 
& 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 \\ 
\hline
Escoger zonas potenciales 
& 1. & Búsqueda de información de mapas de LAI y de tipos de cobertura& X &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \cline{2-21}
& 2. & Escoger lugares extremos &  & X & X &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \cline{ 2-21}
& 3. & Escoger zonas intermedias &  & X & X &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \cline{ 2-21}
& 4. & Seleccionar los mapas a relacionar con las variables atmosféricas&  &  & X &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
\hline
Definir los transectos 
& 1. & Búsqueda de información de DEMs y datos atmosféricos& X &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \cline{ 2-21}
& 2. & Análizar las variables atmosféricas y las topográficas &  & X & X & X &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\ \cline{ 2-21}
& 3. & Establecer los ríos aereos de humedad atmosférica &  &  &  & X & X & X &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
\hline
Evaluar la influencia 
& 1. & Búsqueda de información de evapotranspiración y de temperatura atmosférica & X &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \cline{ 2-21}
& 2. & Realizar gráficas de P Vs distancia, P Vs Cobertura, P Vs LAI, P Vs T y P Vs ETP &  &  &  &  &  & X & X & X & X & X &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \cline{ 2-21}
& 3. & Explicar mediante principios físicos los resultados obtenidos &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & X & X & X & X & X &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
\hline
Otros objetivos 
& 1. & Elaboración de informes escritos y artículos  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & X & X & X & X & X & X & X \\ \cline{ 2-21}
& 2. & Revisión de los resultados obtenidos y ajustes que sean necesarios &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & X & X & X & X & X &  &  \\ \cline{ 2-21}
& 3. & Exposiciones, reuniones y discusiones & X & X & X & X & X & X & X & X & X & X & X & X & X & X & X & X & X & X \\ 
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```